# How to download and show a image from amazon s3 using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, imagedownload

How to download and show a image from amazon s3using zend framework?
I have the data of the image

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3();
                    $data = $s3->getObject($objectname);
```

How to show the image in a page imn my site ?

Answer (score 0):

By documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.service.amazon.s3.html I understand that you have different information on $data. right?
in that format will return it to the picture?
you could paste a debug print object $data?